# Lightning app 'Preview URL' not working?

Tags: lightning-apps

I have been developing a Lightning app which allows me to preview using the /namespace/developername.app however after creating a managed package and publishing it returns the page no longer exists?

Any clues?

Comment: Did you try "/c/developername.app" ?

Comment: c is available before you set up a managed package namespace. After that c/ is no longer available.

Comment: try to use this one **/one/one.app** the standard lightning application URL you've created

Comment: /one/one.app no longer works unless you set your browser to emulate a mobile browser

Answer (score 1):

From **Lightning Components Developer Guide;** 
*"Mark your resources with access="global" to make the resource usable outside of your own org; for example, if you want the resource to be usable in an installed package or by a Lightning App Builder user or a Community Builder user in another org."*

So, please add GLOBAL access modifier to your app like; **aura:application access="GLOBAL"**